# How do I stop my multi-item bootstrap carousel cloning?

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

I'm still fairly new to web design - I've been teaching it to myself and generally able to find solutions to any issues online, however I've come up against something that I don't yet have enough knowledge to fix and can't seem to find a satisfactory answer.

I am trying to create a looping multi-item carousel using Bootstrap, and have modified the code I found [here](http://www.bootply.com/132400) to show 6 images instead of 4.

The html I'm using is more-or-less the same as in the above link (I've just amended the column sizes for the individual images to `col-md-2 col-sm-6 col-xs-12`). I found a few similar questions online and by following these,  I've modified the JS to this:

```
$('#myCarousel').carousel({
 interval: 40000
});

// ARCHIVE CAROUSEL

$('.carousel[data-type="multi"] .item').each(function(){
 var next = $(this).next();
  if (!next.length) {
    next = $(this).siblings(':first');
  }
  next.children(':first-child').clone().appendTo($(this));


  for (var i=0;i<4;i++) {
    next=next.next();
    if (!next.length) {
        next = $(this).siblings(':first');
    }

    next.children(':first-child').clone().appendTo($(this));
  }
});
```

and the CSS to this (for the desktop view):

```
.carousel-inner .active.left { left: -16.7%; }
.carousel-inner .next        { left:  16.7%; }
.carousel-inner .prev        { left: -16.7%; }


.carousel-inner > .item.next,
.carousel-inner > .item.active.right {
  left: 0;
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(16.7%, 0, 0);
  -ms-transform: translate3d(16.7%, 0, 0);
  -o-transform: translate3d(16.7%, 0, 0);
  transform: translate3d(16.7%, 0, 0);
}

.carousel-inner > .item.prev,
.carousel-inner > .item.active.left {
  left: 0;
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(-16.7%, 0, 0);
  -ms-transform: translate3d(-16.7%, 0, 0);
  -o-transform: translate3d(-16.7%, 0, 0);
  transform: translate3d(-16.7%, 0, 0);
}
```

The carousel is working in my browser previews exactly as I want it to - with one problem. The whole carousel is cloning itself 4 times down the page.

I'm aware since this is new to me that it's probably something really obvious and stupid, but I'd really like to understand where I've gone wrong here for my own learning, if anyone can help me?

Many thanks in advance!

Bootply preview [here](http://www.bootply.com/IPcoJpZNwX#) (I'm only really trying to get the desktop view right for now)

[edited for spelling/punctuation]

Answer (score 0):

change line in JS:

```
for (var i=0;i<6;i++) {
```

6 instead of 4.

Comment: Thanks, I've tried this however still having the same issue.

Comment: Revert to original JS files and change number of slides in code. Also take into account what @Appreiron said!

Answer (score 0):

It's actually very nice you are thinking about copying perfomance even you are *fairly new to web design*. I suggest you to create array before defining carousel. Array will contain all your *slides* jQuery objects:

`var slides = [$('.slide-1'), $('.slide-2')];`

Fill it with dynamic elements, or just define existing selectors. It will allow you to **RE-USE** jQuery object instead of creating new one. You are free to append existing blocks as much as you wish.

Another point here - you should define limit of elements in carousel or remove *unseen* slides from it on each iteration etc. It will save you a lot of memory (even if you re-use already existing object, due to append, your container will be expanding).

Hope this help.

Comment: Thank you @Appeiron this sounds sensible, I will need to do a bit more reading on jQuery I think to fully understand, but it gives me something to research.

Comment: Just think about DOM elements as they are Objects. There no need to copy them, you need just to insert them again and again and carousel is a query of them.

Comment: Cheers I'll give this a go and let you know if it works!

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the example, the loop to append items to the carousel should only run twice

`for (var i=0;i<2;i++) {`

You set your's at `4`.

Change `4` to `2`